# how do I parse the http response object coming from asmx

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asmx

```js
$scope.Edit = function (id) {
console.log("edit id : " + id);
$scope.Employee = {};
$scope.eid = id;
var data = JSON.stringify({empid: $scope.eid});
var url = "/services/EmployeeService.asmx/EditEmployee";
$http.post(url, data).then(function (response) {
    $scope.Employee = response.data;
    console.log($scope.Employee.fname);
    console.log($scope.Employee);
    var mydata = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    console.log(mydata);
}, function (response) {
    console.log(response.status);
    console.log(response.statusText);
});

}
```

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string EditEmployee(int empid)
{
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    if (emplist.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Employee emp in emplist)
        {
            if (emp.empId == empid)
            {
                employee.empId = empid;
                employee.fname = emp.fname;
                employee.city = emp.city;
                employee.mobile = emp.mobile;
                employee.country = emp.country;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    List<Employee> elist = new List<Employee>();
    elist.Add(employee);
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(elist);
}
```

This is I got from the response

> Object
>   d:"[{"empId":103,"fname":"sujith","city":"trichy","mobile":"56456456","country":"India"}]"
>   **proto** : Object

how do I parse angular js object. I want to access like this: `$scop.Employee.empId,$scope.Employee.fname`

Thanks & Regards
arun

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the object you are receiving is starting and ending with " " (double quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line

```
$scope.Employee = response.data;
```

with

```
$scope.Employee = response.data.d[0];
```

Comment: Hi Vikas Thakur, thank your for your help, but still it is returning undefined,

Comment: $scope.Employee = response.data.d[0];
                            console.log($scope.Employee.fname); // return undefined

Comment: console.log(response.data.d); //return [{"empId":103,"fname":"sujith","city":"trichy","mobile":"56456456","country":"India"}]
                            console.log(response.data.d[0]);       //return [

Comment: var mydata = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                            console.log(mydata.fname); //return undefined

Comment: @ArunDeveloper Use console.log(response.data.d[0]) to check if its logs single employee object and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This should work :

```
 $scope.Edit = function (id) { console.log("edit id : " + id); $scope.Employee = {}; $scope.eid = id; var data = JSON.stringify({empid: $scope.eid}); var url = "/services/EmployeeService.asmx/EditEmployee"; $http.post(url, data).then(function (response) {
    $scope.Employee = response.data.d[0];
    console.log($scope.Employee.fname);
    console.log($scope.Employee); }, function (response) {
    console.log(response.status);
    console.log(response.statusText); });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $scope.Edit = function (id) {
                        console.log("edit id : " + id);
                        $scope.Employee = {};
                        $scope.eid = id;
                        var data = JSON.stringify({ empid: $scope.eid });
                        var url = "/services/EmployeeService.asmx/EditEmployee";
                        $http.post(url, data).then(function (response) {
                            $scope.Employee = JSON.parse( response.data.d);
                            console.log("empid: " + $scope.Employee.empId);
                            console.log("fname: " + $scope.Employee.fname);
                            console.log("city: " + $scope.Employee.city);
                            console.log("country: " + $scope.Employee.country);                         
                                                   
                        }, function (response) {
                            console.log(response.status);
                            console.log(response.statusText);
                        });
                            
                    }
```

```
enter code here
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string EditEmployee(int empid)
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            if (emplist.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Employee emp in emplist)
                {
                    if (emp.empId == empid)
                    {
                        employee.empId = empid;
                        employee.fname = emp.fname;
                        employee.city = emp.city;
                        employee.mobile = emp.mobile;
                        employee.country = emp.country;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }           
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(employee);
        }
enter code here
```

thank you Vikas Thakur, Abhijeet Jaiswal, it helped me to solved it, now it is working, what mistake is in asmx webservice webmethod I should return Employee object as string, previously I wrongly add it to the list and return the list. the webmethod return type is string so it is not parsing. now it is parsing. thank you both of you helped me.

Comment: Mark one of the answers accepted. This would help others who are in similar situation

Comment: I already marked accepted your answer , it says reputation over more then 15 can be accepted